# HLS -- add an audio track after the video playlist is created

Tags: video, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I have made an HLS playlist for a video file.`FeatureSDPlaylist.m3u8`.

I now want to add in additional audio track to this playlist, for example as shown here: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1761348-multiple-audio-renditions. I would prefer not to encode it all together, as oftentimes we receive a video file first -- at which point it should be encoded and available to play immediately -- but at a later time (perhaps in a month) there may be an additional audio track sent (for example, Spanish) that we want to enable.

How would this be done?

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are trying to do this? You should be able to encode the audio at a later date and then add it to the manifest.

Comment: You just modify the master playlist and add another track to an audio group like in the example. You'll have to make sure your new audio track is timecode-aligned with your others streams to avoid synchronizations issues.